# install ros on debian wheezy

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I am trying to install ROS indigo on a Beaglebone Black with debian wheezy. I have followed the tutorial and it worked until the step 1.3. The commands `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` and `sudo easy_install pip` were ok but when I execute `sudo pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall` then I get the following message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting rosdep
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rosdep (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rosdep
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thank you for your help!
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210653/install-ros-on-debian-wheezy/) by [CarlosRoncal](https://answers.ros.org/users/22365/carlosroncal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could it be that this is only a warning not related to your problem?
http://fossies.org/diffs/requests/2.5.3_vs_2.6.0/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py-diff.html

Anyway wheezy is oldstable, so I'd recommend update to jessie.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0